# Any way to programmatically force IE8 to open popups in a new window instead of a tab?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to programmatically instruct IE8 to open a popup in a new window rather than a new tab?  I know that IE supports modal windows but I have a bunch of legacy code with ordinary popups.

**Update:**

I am using Javascript's window.open() method to create popup windows.  However, when a user has their IE8 settings set to "Always open popups in a new tab", the popup is launched in a new tab rather than a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one else is chiming in... After doing further research, it seems that you cannot force a pop-up to open into a new window when an IE8 user has the following browser setting enabled: *Tools>>Internet Options>>Tabs>>When a pop-up is encountered:>>Always open pop-ups in a new tab*.

Since I am in an Intranet environment, I have the option of locking down a users IE settings to either "Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should open" or "Always open pop-ups in a new window".

I don't really care to exercise the above option so in order to get the desired user experience, I will resort to making one of the following code changes:

1. Convert existing pop-ups to [IE specific Modal Dialogs using the showModalDialog() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28VS.85%29.aspx).
2. Convert existing pop-ups to Javascript Modal Dialogs using [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) or some other [jQuery plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/modal+dialog+type%3Aproject_project).

Comment: Have you tried giving it a width and height. I found that in FF it does spawn a new window instead of tab once you gave it a width and height.

Comment: Is there any other solution to override this behavior via javascript apart from Modal Dialogs ?

Answer (score 2):

Using html, the best you can do is set open page target to blank. Everything else is controlled by the client side and they can choose to open it in a new window or tab.

However, you can use javascript to open the window. Create Link to open in new window [here](http://javascript.internet.com/generators/popup-window.html)

Answer (score 0):

> If you opt to let Internet Explorer decide how to display pop-ups, it
>   will display the pop-up in a new window if the pop-up specifies size
>   or display requirements. Otherwise, the pop-up is displayed in a new
>   tab.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Tabbed-browsing-in-Internet-Explorer-8-frequently-asked-questions

So if you don't set any specific window requirements and it should open in a new tab, unless a user has changed these settings.